# XDocument Parse Ignore Chinese Characters

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a XML string which contains some chinese characters like `�菅࿼Ჽ탽᫴`. So When Parsing it with `XDocument.Parse` it is throwing the below exception.

`System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x01, is an invalid character`

I tried converting the xml string to `UTF-8`. But still the same issue.

Any Ideas?

**Update:**

XML Contains lots of elements in it, but on using the below answer it is ignoring all the other elements but just converting the elements which has special characters, Is there anything can be done with `XDocument` instead of `XElement`?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910518/how-to-read-xml-file-in-encoding-utf-8

Comment: Chinese characters are Unicode not utf8.

Comment: @jdweng, Do I need to use Unicode Encoder?

Comment: Yes, your string is corrupted.  The Parse method uses a string.  If you are getting a character 0x01 is means the string data was read using an encoding that wasn't Unicode.  Most File/Stream methods default to ASCII encoding which will corrupt Unicode.  Make sure any method you are using to read the file/stream has Encoding.Unicode.

Comment: @jdweng Unicode is a character set, UTF8 is an encoding.  The two are not comparable.  UTF8 encodes Unicode characters to binary. `Encoding.Unicode` is actually UTF16.  As an aside, nearly all File/Stream reader/writers use UTF8 by default, not ASCII,

Comment: The most likely issue here is that your XML has been incorrectly decoded.  Presuming you are the one decoding the binary data, you should find out what it was encoded with.

Comment: Let me check that and update here. Thank you!

Comment: Charles : A character/sting is two bytes wide.  Using UTF8 encoding takes Unicode and put it into two characters which is incorrect.  Using Unicode Encoding packs the character into one or two bytes based on the data.  I know the difference between a character set and the encoding, but you may not.

Comment: Post your xml content here

Comment: @jdweng How is UTF8 'incorrect'?  It encodes all possible Unicode characters.  Your statement that 'Chinese characters are Unicode not UTF8' doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Doesn't UTF8 pack each byte into a separate character, while unicode packs one and two bytes into one character?

Comment: UTF8 represents a character as 1-4 bytes, depending on the character. I think you're referring to UTF16 (which Microsoft erroneously refer to as 'Unicode' - UTF16 is just a 'way of representing Unicode' it isn't *the* Unicode encoding).  You can see in [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Unicode_Transformation_Format_and_Universal_Character_Set) that UTF8 and UTF16 are just two ways of encoding Unicode characters (UTF standing for *Unicode Transformation Format*).

Answer (score 2):

Use XmlReader with XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters set to false will solve your issue.

**UPDATE**

Here is what I'd used to load my japanese xml file.

```
string xmlText = "your xml data";
XElement node;
XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
xrs.CheckCharacters = false;
using (XmlReader rd = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlText), xrs))
{
    node = XElement.Load(rd);
}
```

Comment: Also I want to use it with `XDocument`

Comment: Thank you! When i tried to convert it to xml string again `node.ToString()`, I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Have you ever try node.Value instead?

Comment: Sorry, One last question, It is not containing the whole xml document, but only the node which contains chinese characters.. Any Idea on this?

Comment: Well, update your question with more detail on the xml file or ask it in another question.